# Stop WP_Query->get_posts from running on a category page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a big problem with one of my sites. I have one category that stores other categories. The problem is that WordPress uses `WP_Query->get_posts` and gets all the posts on this main category page. Even tho I deleted everything inside and I left only `the_header` and `the_footer` it still does the query. Structure is like this Category>Subcategory>posts. The problem is that WordPress is doing the query for all posts that are in my subcategories.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (13,14,15,24,25,26,27,28,29,102,130,154,256) )
```

The query is much larger than this, it takes around 22 seconds to load.

My code works fine, if I move the code in a custom page it loads in 0.80, but in the custom_category page loads in 22-28 seconds. I would like to prevent `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID` from running in this category. I can't change anything about the URLs since the site is in production and has really good positions. Need to do something ASAP and I'm out of ideas.

I've tried this: https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/wordpress-database-queries-speed-sql_calc_found_rows but it doesn't matter, still the same loading speed.

This is my code:

```
<?php
GLOBAL $wpdb;
$subcategorii = $wpdb->get_results("select term_id, name, slug from $wpdb->terms where is_mother_cat = '1' ORDER BY term_id DESC");

// total numar de postari de afisat
$per_page = 28;

// extragem numarul total de postari
$total_rows = count($subcategorii);

// setam numarul total de pagini
$pages = ceil($total_rows / $per_page);

// extragem page curenta
$current_page = (@$_GET['page'] ? @$_GET['page'] : 1);
$current_page = ($total_rows > 0) ? min($pages, $current_page) : 1;

// offset
$start = $current_page * $per_page - $per_page;

// salvam in array doar postarile din page curenta
$subcategorii_array = array_slice($subcategorii, $start, $per_page);

foreach ($subcategorii_array as $subcats) {
    echo '<li class="border-radius-5 box-shadow">';
    //z_taxonomy_image($subcats->term_id, 'thumbnail', array('alt' => $subcats->name));
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($subcats->term_id).'"><span>'.$subcats->name.'</span></a>';
    echo '</li>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem with this function that I found. But another one appeard.
Now the WP_Term_Query->get_terms() is called on that page calling all the posts. At least is 10 seconds faster. Anyone any ideea what is happening here?

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*
FROM wp_terms AS t
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category')
```

Function that fixes the problem:

```
/* apply this filter only on relevant to you pages */
    function mb_bail_main_wp_query( $sql, WP_Query $wpQuery ) {
        if ( $wpQuery->is_main_query() && is_category(8133) ) {
            /* prevent SELECT FOUND_ROWS() query*/
            $wpQuery->query_vars['no_found_rows'] = true;
    
            /* prevent post term and meta cache update queries */
            $wpQuery->query_vars['cache_results'] = false;
    
            return false;
        }
        return $sql;
    }
    add_action( 'posts_request', 'mb_bail_main_wp_query', 10, 2 );
```